# Can't get BundleInstall working for Vundle

Tags: vim, ubuntu

I'm trying to get vundle working. Here's the error I get when I run :BundleInstall 
    E117: Unknown function: vundle#installer#new

Here is my .vim:

```
.
├── bundle
│   └── vundle
│       ├── autoload
│       │   ├── vundle
│       │   │   ├── config.vim
│       │   │   ├── installer.vim
│       │   │   └── scripts.vim
│       │   └── vundle.vim
│       ├── doc
│       │   └── vundle.txt
│       ├── LICENSE-MIT.txt
│       ├── README.md
│       └── test
│           ├── files
│           │   └── test.erl
│           ├── minirc.vim
│           └── vimrc
└── colors
    └── xoria256.vim
```

Here is my .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'msanders/snipmate.vim'
Bundle 'mattn/zencoding-vim'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'L9'
Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'

filetype plugin indent on
colorscheme xoria256
set relativenumber
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set cindent
set virtualedit=all
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim (usually just
" /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/debian.vim) and sourced by the call to :runtime
" you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those settings, you should
" do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim will be overwritten
" everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.  It is recommended to
" make changes after sourcing debian.vim since it alters the value of the
" 'compatible' option.

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian.
runtime! debian.vim

" Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" NOTE: debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'.  Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER setting 'compatible'.
"set compatible

" Vim5 and later versions support syntax highlighting. Uncommenting the next
" line enables syntax highlighting by default.
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
" turn on this option as well
"set background=dark

" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
"if has("autocmd")
"  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
"endif

" Uncomment the following to have Vim load indentation rules and plugins
" according to the detected filetype.
"if has("autocmd")
"  filetype plugin indent on
"endif

" The following are commented out as they cause vim to behave a lot
" differently from regular Vi. They are highly recommended though.
"set showcmd    " Show (partial) command in status line.
"set showmatch    " Show matching brackets.
"set ignorecase   " Do case insensitive matching
"set smartcase    " Do smart case matching
"set incsearch    " Incremental search
"set autowrite    " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
"set hidden             " Hide buffers when they are abandoned
"set mouse=a    " Enable mouse usage (all modes)

" Source a global configuration file if available
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
```

vundle installed py pathogen? Perfectly... but pathogen don't want work!
Just install only one package manager. I read your previous question and i think you need to clean all vim directories e.g. ~/.vim, /usr/share/vim etc. and reinstall vim. After that install only pathogen or vundle by reading plugin installation instructions. And finally install you favorite plugins by the pathogen (git clone) or vundle.

Comment: Yup, that's what I did, late into the wee hours last night. Thanks, Alex! Also, you can install pathogen via vundle, which is kind of interesting.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a reinstall might help. Much better.

Answer (score 26):

I resolved this problem by move 'runtime! debian.vim' before vundle code.

Comment: Worked for me, too!

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I got the exact same error (and therefore unability to use Vundle) without using or having used pathogen:

```
E117: Fonction inconnue : vundle#installer#list
```

In my case, the following option is what caused Vundle to not function:

~/.vimrc

```
" Syntaxe pour Perl
    autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
    set runtimepath=~/.vim,/vimfiles
```

(for the record that was the very last option in my .vimrc :-o )

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was when i had non latin characters in rtp path. Moving vimfiles directory to some path with latin chars only solved it for me.